# a php function to check if a value is 'falsy', but let pass 0

Tags: php

I need to check if a variable is not:

'', [], null, false

But check must pass if variable is

0, 0.0, '0', [0], ['0']

At this time, I came up with this:

```
function is_empty($item){
  if(!isset($item)) return true; // null

  if(is_string($item)){
    $s = trim($item);
    if($s != '0' && empty($s)) return true; // empty string, let '0'
  }

  if(is_array($item) && empty($item)) return true; // empty array
    
  return false; // not empty
}
```

Anything I can do better?

Comment: After `$s = trim($item);` it doesn't appear that `$s` is used... should it be?

Comment: How about `return $s !=='' && $s !== [] && $s !== null && $s !== false;`?

Comment: Is `0`, `0.0`, `'0'`, `[0]`, `['0']` an exhaustive list?  Are you also allowing `'0000.0000'` and `[".00"]`?  I just want to make sure that I am understanding the boundaries of your requirement. @Luca

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ you're right! Thank you!

Comment: @slepic Mmm thank you, I must think of it!

Comment: @mickmackusa No I'm not allowing them but in the current application those kind of values will never be used. Anyway, for a generic utility function, I should take them into account, you're right, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is_numeric()` to cover all numeric-like values, including numeric strings, integers and floats. Non-numeric values don't need additional handling, they can all be covered by `empty()`. So this is enough:

```
function is_empty($item)
{
    return empty($item) && !is_numeric($item);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/LWc3M

In case you also need to check if string is not empty after `trim()`:

```
function is_empty($item)
{
    return (empty($item) && !is_numeric($item)) || (is_string($item) && trim($item) === '');
}
```

https://3v4l.org/UeF6F

Note the parentheses are not necessary but I like to keep them for readability and to avoid potential errors due to operator precedence.

If you're using PHP 7+, don't forget to add return typehint:

```
function is_empty($item): bool
```

And on PHP 8 you can add `mixed` argument typehint:

```
function is_empty(mixed $item): bool
```

Comment: @mickmackusa if you chek his examples you'll also find single-element arrays containing zeros :)

Comment: @Sharky, brilliant, thank you!